# How many free-action tokens can I spend at once?

Tags: beyonder

Many Powers confer "tokens" that can be spent to cause some effect. The Power descriptions always include this line:

> Target gains 1/3/6/10 tokens that can be spent as a free action

followed by something like "to do X" or "to cause Y".

Does this mean that each token, *individually*, is spent as a free action? Or does it mean that the token**s** *collectively* are spent as a free action? In other words, how many free-action tokens can I spend at once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Unless the Power description states otherwise, you should only allow one token to be used at a time.

The "individual token" reading was probably intended, but the grammar of "can be spent" is ambiguous, and the Rulebook offers no other guidance. Therefore, you *could* allow multiple tokens to be spent at once, if you wanted to. You should not do this. Doing so completely breaks the game.

The most egregious game-breaker might be Karmic Balance, one of the Emotion Powers, whose description states:

> Target gains 1/3/6/10 tokens that can be spent as a free
>   action to give +1 to any roll. Add +5 levels to increase the
>   bonus by an additional +1.

A mid-level character will consistently get a moderate or major success on this Power, while incurring only one or two Fatigue for it. If you allow all of these tokens to be spent at once, that means your mid-level Charismatic can give a +12 bonus *to every roll* essentially for free. No one will ever fail a roll again, all Powers will succeed at the major or complete level, and so on. This robs the game of challenge, thrill, and fun.

This is not the only case where spending multiple tokens would hurt the game, but it's a pretty blatant one. Save multiple-token-use for those Powers that include phrases like "spend X tokens" or "per token spent".